# In a pandas dataframe with a MultiIndex, how to conditionally fill missing values with group means?

Tags: pandas, multi-index, fillna

Setup:

```py
# create a MultiIndex
dfx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    list('ab'),
    list('cd'),
    list('xyz'),
], names=['idx1', 'idx2', 'idx3'])

# create a dataframe that fits the index
df = pd.DataFrame([None, .9, -.08, -2.11, 1.09, .38, None, None, -.37, -.86, 1.51, -.49], columns=['random_data'])
df.set_index(dfx, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
                        random_data
idx1    idx2    idx3    
a       c       x       NaN
                y       0.90
                z      -0.08

        d       x      -2.11
                y       1.09
                z       0.38

b       c       x       NaN
                y       NaN
                z      -0.37

        d       x      -0.86
                y       1.51
                z      -0.49
```

Within this index hierarchy,  I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. When a value is missing within `[idx1, idx2, idx3]`, fill `NaN` with the group mean of `[idx1, idx2`]
2. When multiple values are missing within `[idx1, idx2, idx3]`, fill `NaN` with the group mean of `[idx1]`

I have tried `df.apply(lambda col: col.fillna(col.groupby(by='idx1').mean()))` as a way to solve #2, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

**UPDATE**

OK, so I have this solved in parts, but still at a loss about how to apply these conditionally:

For case #1:

`df.unstack().apply(lambda col: col.fillna(col.mean()), axis=1).stack()`.

I verified that the correct value was filled by looking at this:

`df.groupby(by=['idx1', 'idx2']).mean()`,

but it also replaces the missing values that I am trying to handle differently in case #2.

Similarly for #2:

`df.unstack().unstack().apply(lambda col: col.fillna(col.mean()), axis=1).stack().stack()`

verified the values replaced were correct by looking at

`df.groupby(by=['idx1']).mean()`

but it also applies to case #1, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved it.

First, I made a dataframe containing counts by group of non-missing values:

```py
truth_table = df.apply(lambda row: row.count(), axis = 1).groupby(by=['idx1', 'idx2']).sum()

>> truth_table

idx1  idx2
a     c       2
      d       3
b     c       1
      d       3
dtype: int64
```

Then set up a dataframe (one for each case I'm trying to resolve) containing the group means:

```
means_ab = x.groupby(by=['idx1']).mean()

>> means_ab

idx1    
a    0.0360
b   -0.0525

means_abcd = x.groupby(by=['idx1', 'idx2']).mean()

>> means_abcd

idx1    idx2    
a       c    0.410000
d           -0.213333
b       c   -0.370000
d            0.053333
```

Given the structure of my data, I know:

- Case #1 is analogous to `truth_table` having **exactly one** missing value in a given index grouping of `[idx1, idx2]` (e.g., these are the `NaN` values I want to replace with values from `means_abcd`)
- Case #2 is analogous to `truth_table` having **more than one** missing value in a given index grouping of `[idx1, idx2]` (e.g., these are the `NaN` values I want to replace with values from `means_ab`

```py
fix_case_2 = df.combine_first(df[truth_table > 1].fillna(means_ab, axis=1))

>> fix_case_2

idx1    idx2    idx3    
a       c       x     NaN
                y     0.9000
                z    -0.0800
        d       x    -2.1100
                y     1.0900
                z     0.3800
b       c       x    -0.0525 *
                y    -0.0525 *
                z    -0.3700
        d       x    -0.8600
                y     1.5100
                z    -0.4900

df = fix_case_2.combine_first(df[truth_table == 1].fillna(means_abcd, axis=1))

>> df

idx1    idx2    idx3    
a       c       x     0.4100 *
                y     0.9000
                z    -0.0800
        d       x    -2.1100
                y     1.0900
                z     0.3800
b       c       x    -0.0525 *
                y    -0.0525 *
                z    -0.3700
        d       x    -0.8600
                y     1.5100
                z    -0.4900
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way of doing this, but the following should achieve your desired result:

```py
def get_null_count(df, group_levels, column):
    result = (
        df.loc[:, column]
          .groupby(group_levels)
          .transform(lambda x: x.isnull().sum())
    ).astype("int")
    return result

def fill_groups(
    df, 
    count_group_levels,
    column,
    missing_count_idx_map
):
    null_counts = get_null_count(
        df, count_group_levels, column
    )

    condition_masks = {
        count: ((null_counts == count) & df[col].isnull()).to_numpy()
        for count in missing_count_idx_map.keys()
    }
    condition_values = {
        count: df.loc[:, column]
                 .groupby(indicies)
                 .transform("mean")
                 .to_numpy()
        for count, indicies in missing_count_idx_map.items()
    }
    # Defaults
    condition_masks[0] = (~df[col].isnull()).to_numpy()
    condition_values[0] = df[col].to_numpy()

    sorted_keys = sorted(missing_count_idx_map.keys()) + [0]
    conditions = [
        condition_masks[count]
        for count in sorted_keys
    ]
    values = [
        condition_values[count]
        for count in sorted_keys
    ]

    result = np.select(conditions, values)
    return result

col = "random_data"
missing_count_idx_map = {
    1: ['idx1', "idx2"],
    2: ['idx1']
}
df["filled"] = fill_groups(
    df, ['idx1', 'idx2'], col, missing_count_idx_map
)
```

`df` then looks like:

```
                random_data  filled
idx1 idx2 idx3                     
a    c    x             NaN   -0.20
          y            1.16    1.16
          z           -1.56   -1.56
     d    x            0.47    0.47
          y           -0.54   -0.54
          z           -0.30   -0.30
b    c    x             NaN   -0.40
          y             NaN   -0.40
          z            0.29    0.29
     d    x            0.98    0.98
          y           -0.41   -0.41
          z           -2.46   -2.46
```

Comment: The mean for group `{idx1:a, idx2:c}` is supposed to be `0.41`, and group `{idx1: b`} is supposed to be `-0.0525`

Comment: @ChristopherCompeau You can see the values that I used do indeed match the calculated means.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you may try this. Get `mean` of level`idx1` and `mean` of level [`idx1`, `idx2`]. Fillna use mean of [`idx1`,`idx2`]. Next, use `mask` to assign rows of groups having more than 1 `NaN` by `mean` of `idx1`

```
Sample `df`:
                random_data
idx1 idx2 idx3
a    c    x             NaN
          y           -0.09
          z           -0.01
     d    x           -1.30
          y           -0.11
          z            1.33
b    c    x             NaN
          y             NaN
          z            0.74
     d    x           -1.44
          y            0.50
          z           -0.61

df1_m = df.mean(level='idx1')
df12_m = df.mean(level=['idx1', 'idx2'])
m = df.isna().groupby(level=['idx1', 'idx2']).transform('sum').gt(1)

df_filled = df.fillna(df12_m).mask(m & df.isna(), df1_m)

Out[110]:
                random_data
idx1 idx2 idx3
a    c    x         -0.0500
          y         -0.0900
          z         -0.0100
     d    x         -1.3000
          y         -0.1100
          z          1.3300
b    c    x         -0.2025
          y         -0.2025
          z          0.7400
     d    x         -1.4400
          y          0.5000
          z         -0.6100
```

Comment: The mean for group `{idx1:a, idx2:c}` is supposed to be `0.41`, and group `{idx1: b`} is supposed to be `-0.0525`

Comment: My sample data is different from your latest sample data, so the output is different. That is the reason I provided my sample `df` in the answer. Originally, you provided codes to create sample data using `random`. I used that code to create the my sample `df`. You now edited to use a fixed sample `df`. If you apply my code to your latest sample. You will get `0.4100` and `-0.0525` as you expected.